# Onclick of link in page1 should redirect to page2 and find a div with specific id in page2 and add a class to it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 pages, page1.html and page2.html, onclick of a link in page1 should load page 2 and find a div in page2, that contains the data-id as id and add class selected to that id. Can someone help me to achieve this. 
For example
Page1:

```
<ul> 
  <li><a href="page2.html" data-id="minion">minion</a></li>
  <li><a href="page2.html" data-id="jack">Jack</a></li>
  <li><a href="page2.html" data-id="mango">mango</a></li>
</ul>
```

Page2:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="minion"></div>
  <div id="jack"></div>
  <div id="mango"></div>
</div>
```

Results in page2, on click  minion

```
<div id="minion" class="selected"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I can understand from your question is you want to redirect to another page and target specific div with an id.

you can achieve this by placing the id tag at the end of the anchor tag.

```html
  <ul>
    <li><a href="page2.html#minion" data-id="minion">minion</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html#jack" data-id="jack">Jack</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html#mango" data-id="mango">mango</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: you are right and also I need to add class="selected" for the id target